# How do I change the block size?

Tags: cognito-forms

How to make each field smaller? How do you make the block size smaller? How do you make the font smaller?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of fonts, you can customize the form's font type/size/color in the [Style Editor](http://help.cognitoforms.com/customizing-form-styles) (located under the Publish page in your form builder).

To change the size of fields, click on an individual field and select "Make Bigger" or "Make Smaller". Additionally, with the upcoming [resizable fields](https://trello.com/c/qsMGlSXd/15-resizable-fields) release, you will be able to click and drag your fields to a variety of custom sizes.